# Where is the error in my button in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, game-development

In unity i have made a button and a script to open another scene when pressed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start");
        SceneManager.LoadScene((SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex) + 1);        
    }
}
```

But when i play the button to play the scene, without pressing the button it opens another scene which i have added in the build settings

Comment: Move the `SceneManager.LoadScene` to the button click handler rather than `Start`.  The latter will run immediately

Answer (score 1):

`Start` method is called automatically almost on `MonoBehaviour` instance creation. You can see full `MonoBehaviour` lifecycle [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

If you want to call something by clicking the button, you need to assign a callback to it and place your code there. [Here is a simple video on how to make it work](https://youtu.be/gSfdCke3684?t=193).